# Intellij - copy paste code to Onenote 2016 lost spaces with formatting

Tags: intellij-idea, copy-paste, onenote

When I copy the code and comments from Intellij to Onenote. Surprisingly it lost its spaces. Is there any way to solve this problem. Please see screenshot below

[image: Intellij to Onenote -Copy paste with formatting]

what I am looking for is with formatting and indentation.

Comment: Does it happen with any file type? Does paste to other application work Ok?

Comment: I've tried with Python and Q/KDB+, and spaces gone. IntelliJ 2020.2.3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A short term workaround (this has worked for me with other IDEs) is to paste the code in another application like Microsoft Word, and then paste the code in OneNote.